# gradle issue on ./gradlew eclipse vs. gradle plugin

Tags: gradle

ok, 3 bugs below I 'think' but if they are not let me know. (I do LOVE the customizability of gradle and these are corner case bugs for sure but still inconsistent behaviors)

- gradle version 2.14.1
- Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 build id 20160613-1800
- Buildship, Eclipse Plugins for gradle 1.0.20v20160901-0734

I LOVE making things seamless so I really wanted to make things seamless on using eclipse with this project https://github.com/deanhiller/webpiecesExample as a test run.

BUG 1: Instead, I found a bug in the eclipse buildship gradle plugin that does not bring in -parameters to the project settings like ./gradlew eclipse does :(.

I have the following that makes my gradle compile with parameters (and ./gradlew eclipse generates the correct settings file while buildship ecilpse gradle plugin does not)

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options.collect {options ->
    options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
}
```

BUG 2: so then I switch to ./gradlew eclipse.  That then has a different bug in that it generates two src/main/java when using a section like this.....

```
sourceSets {
//For testing, we need to put the html files on the classpath which are co-located with the controllers
extraTest {
    resources {
        srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
        includes = ["**/*.html", "**/*.tag"]
    }
}
test {
    resources {
        //This ADDS src/test/java/**/*.html and we still read in src/test/resources/**
        source extraTest.resources
    }
}
}
```

BUG 3: In trying to figure this all out, I finally found out gradlew cleanEclipse does not clean stuff that was generated by gradlew eclipse specifically the .settings folder :(.  I basically can do a ./gradlew eclipse and then gradlew cleanEclipse and they don't delete what was created :(.

FEATURE REQUEST 1: The application plugin I had to hack like this....(definitely read my comments as the solution ended up not working and I had to hack it differently).

[How to configure gradle application plugin to set my user.dir to the location of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230739/how-to-configure-gradle-application-plugin-to-set-my-user-dir-to-the-location-of)

You should totally be able to tell the application plugin that one desires the application directory to be where the program starts no matter what directory I start the application from....that was very frustrating to fix all that.

I still love gradle.  I am just getting very down and dirty in the details here and hope that eventually these nitpicks can be fixed.

Comment: That's the Eclipse for you... Open source and developed for years and still has annoying unfixed bugs here and there... The reason I switched to Intellij, excels in stability and its gradle plugin works fine.

Comment: @Alexiy heh, try intellij...it was an even worse experience :(.  I am trying to get that working and report all those issues today as well.

Comment: @Alexiy intellij completely failed so far, but I posted this post.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322753/how-to-add-resource-files-in-intellij-from-src-main-java-directoryintellij-2016  perhaps someone will know how to fix it so I can work in intellij for a while.

Comment: Ok, how about using native gradle distribution? And of the latest version.